# Can functions implement an interface in Go

Tags: function, go, interface

I'm trying to make an interface similar to [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler). For certain endpoints of my API I need a APNS token included in the query or I need to respond with `http.StatusBadRequest`.

I want the type `DeviceHandlerFunc` to implement `ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` and automatically parse the token and call itself with the token:

```
type DeviceHandlerFunc func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, string)

func (f DeviceHandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    token := req.URL.Query().Get("token")

    if token == "" {
        http.Error(res, "token missing from query", http.StatusBadRequest)
    } else {
        f(res, req, token)
    }
}
```

Then from `main.go`:

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", getDevice)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", mux))
}

func getDevice(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, token string) {
    // Do stuff with token...
}
```

This causes a compiler error:

```
main.go:22:13: cannot use getDevice (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, string)) as type http.Handler in argument to mux.Handle:
    func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, string) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

In my mind I couldn't be more clear that the type `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, string)` implements `http.Handler`. What am I doing wrong?

*Sample code [as playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FcpXZVJ30V).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DeviceHandlerFunc` type indeed implements [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler). That's not the problem.

But your `getDevice()` function is **not** of type `DeviceHandlerFunc`, it's of type `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, string)` (which is an unnamed type which obviously does not implement `http.Handler`).

To make it work, use a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
mux.Handle("/", DeviceHandlerFunc(getDevice))
```

You can convert `getDevice` to `DeviceHandlerFunc` as the underlying type of `DeviceHandlerFunc` is the same as the type of `getDevice`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uJhqNTyXB8).

The following would also work:

```
var f DeviceHandlerFunc = getDevice
mux.Handle("/", f)
```

Here type of `f` is obviously `DeviceHandlerFunc`. And you can assign `getDevice` to `f` as [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules apply, namely this one:

> [A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:]
>
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type.